# Checking 2 values to find same string

Tags: sql, compare

I am trying to compare 2 varchar fields to see if they are similar and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to find my answer anywhere.  I've tried using SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE, but they don't give me what I need.

This is what I am trying to do:-

```
Column 1   Column 2    Column 3
123 456    456 123    Should show 1 or "Yes"
123 456    789 987    Should show 0 or "No"
```

This will generally be a sort code and account number, but they quite often appear swapped round in the fields so I am trying to weed them out

Any help would be great

Comment: well, if you know the length of each string part, you could use something like SUBSTR to compare the four different combinations. But it's just a dirty way to check. There are probably some cleaner ways. That's the reason I'm not posting this as an answer ;)

Comment: You only want to account for full matches, ie '12' is contained in '123', should that be '1' or should do you need full chunks separated by the space to be similar?  And which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: why dont you use

    SELECT * FROM Column 2 WHERE Column 1 <> Column 2? this should bring back the different values

Comment: @DevN00B The value of col1 is the full string '123 456' as per the example in the question, he wants '123 456' to be considered a match to '456 123'

Comment: @Chris Upton - mysql or sql server?

Comment: @GoatCO. Ah...i may be wrong but i think what he is trying to do is say they are the same numbers but the wrong way rong and the second one is a completely different number as he says at the bottom "week them out"

Comment: @DevN00B That makes sense, I was assuming he wanted to correct the swapped numbers, hence differentiating between swapped numbers and different numbers.  But we are left to speculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which RDBMS you are using, but this works in SQL Server to split the fields:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) = '123 456'
SELECT LEFT(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',@str)-1)''
        ,RIGHT(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@str))-1)
```

In your case, assuming both sides must match:

```
SELECT col1
      ,col2
      ,CASE WHEN col1 = col2 THEN 1
            WHEN LEFT(col1,CHARINDEX(' ',col1)-1) = RIGHT(col2,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(col2))-1)
               AND LEFT(col2,CHARINDEX(' ',col2)-1) = RIGHT(col1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(col1))-1) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END
FROM YourTable
```

If you're trying to isolate matching numbers that are out of order, then you can give the first and second `WHEN` lines different `THEN` values.